# How to test behavior of Auto Layout constraints in xib without launching app?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xib

I'd would like to see how the controls on my xib behave without actually launching the app.

In the Xcode documentation it says "[t]o test the behavior of Auto Layout constraints when you are editing a nib file, hold down the Command key and resize the window."

Does this only apply to OS X or is there a way to do it with an iOS app as well?

Answer (score 3):

In xcode 5 you can preview how your view will look in different device screen and OS's. Open the assistant editor (Command+alt+enter) set it to preview and select the viewController you want to test. In the preview tab you can change screen size and iOS version.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that space. But it only lets me choose between iOS6-/7 and 3.5 and 4" screens. I'm actually trying to get away with a single xib for all iOS devices on this view. BTW, the shortcut is `CMD+ALT+,` on my system

Answer (score 1):

What I have found to work is to switch your view controller under Properties -> Simulated Metrics -> Size to Freeform.

Your view should now be resizable with the mouse and the constraints will be in effect during resizing.

Comment: Thanks, this was the first thing I tried, but was doing it while holding command like the documentation says to. While holding command all of the objects stay fixed in place, but just resizing normally does the trick.

Comment: I have found it to be a little twitchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing full screen view, you cannot scale it but you may apply retina 3.5-inch form factor to view it in different height.

If you are putting views in container like UIScrollView,  you may rescale the container to see if subviews moving or resizing as designed.

It is powerful when you are designing stand-alone xib for cell or custom views.